# Remove empty key,pairs from JSON using python

Tags: python, json

i have json data

```
data = 
[
{"A": "1", "C": "", "B": "2", "E": "4", "D": "3"}, 
{"A": "", "C": "6", "B": "5", "E": "7", "D": ""}, 
{"A": "", "C": "", "B": "", "E": "8", "D": ""}, 
{"A": "", "C": "", "B": "9", "E": "", "D": "10"}
]
```

I want to remove empty key/value using python so that it looks like this

```
data = 
[
{"A": "1", "B": "2", "E": "4", "D": "3"}, 
{"C": "6", "B": "5", "E": "7"}, {"E": "8"}, 
{"B": "9", "D": "10"}
]
```

Comment: Load it in memory with json module. Start with: `import json`

Comment: Can you please explain more. Sample code to remove empty key/value will be helpful.

Comment: please try to always be detailed and don't submit questions that are unclear or too broad

Comment: I am not sure what information you are looking for. I have asked specific question with sample data and output i am trying to get. Anyway I got the solution from Ajax1234's answer. It worked the exact way i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
data = [
  {"A": "1", "C": "", "B": "2", "E": "4", "D": "3"}, 
  {"A": "", "C": "6", "B": "5", "E": "7", "D": ""}, 
  {"A": "", "C": "", "B": "", "E": "8", "D": ""}, 
  {"A": "", "C": "", "B": "9", "E": "", "D": "10"}
 ]
new_data = [{a:b for a, b in i.items() if b} for i in data]
```

Output:

```
[{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'E': '4', 'D': '3'}, {'C': '6', 'B': '5', 'E': '7'}, {'E': '8'}, {'B': '9', 'D': '10'}]
```

Comment: @Mike glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please accept it.

Comment: Was trying to accept it as answer, But couldn't find that button. Might be it will appear after sometime. Will check back after sometime.

Comment: @Mike it is the grey checkbox, just to the left of the answer.

Comment: Ah.. found it. Sorry was new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Mike no problem! Glad to help!